# Get value of String Integer from created string

Tags: java, string, integer

So say if I had a series of String Integers with name, i: `i1`, `i2`, `i3` etc but wanted to make up each name with a combination of a String and an Integer like:

```
String i1 = "abc";
String i2 = "bca";
String i3 = "cba";

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    String a = "i" + i;
    int aa = Integer.parseInt(a);
    ArrayList<String>.add(aa);
}
```

How could I achieve this? This for loop just adds "i1", "i2" and "i3" to the List, instead of "abc", "bca" and "cba".

Comment: Java does not (and cannot) evaluate variable names dynamically. Use an array, map, or list.

Comment: I thought by using parseInt("i1") it would make aa the same value of i1 and therefore revert back to its value, "abc" etc. I guess it just makes a new Integer then?

Comment: You should always try to run the code before you ask a question. And read the javadoc for `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: I stated I did. It adds i1, i2, i3 to the List. It was just a question out of curiosity to help a better understanding of the Java language.

Comment: And I don't understand why the question was voted down, is it not a valid question?

Answer (score 4):

Ah, I misunderstood your question at first. Yes, you can do what you want to do trough reflection.

```
public class Main {
    private String i1 = "abc";
    private String i2 = "bca";
    private String i3 = "cba";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            String a = "i" + i;
            String f = null;
            try {
                f = (String) this.getClass().getDeclaredField(a).get(this);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abc
bca
cba
```

Keypoints:

- [`getDeclaredField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) - returns a private field in the given class
- [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) - returns the value from a field in the given object

It should be noted though that you should look into using a `Map<String, String>` structure first. Other answers already provide the explanation for this.

Comment: @kocko: because this is the answer to the question he actually asked, unlike the different approach you posted. My answer literally contains one line of code that does the thing, everything else is just a try-catch block or code used to demonstrate the concept. I'd hardly call that complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use some of the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) implementations.

For example:

```
String[] words = { "abc", "bca", "cba" };
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    String a = "i" + i;
    map.put(a, words[i - 1]);
}
```

At the end, the map looks like:

```
--key-- | --value--
-------------------
  "i1"  |  "abc"
  "i2"  |  "bca"
  "i3"  |  "cba"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Integer.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29), one of the options is able to use alphabetic characters as well as numerical to represent the `String`.

You will also need to create a `List` to add your `String`s to.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    list.add(whatever);
}
```

Or if you are trying to store a mapping of String to Integer, then you should look at `Map`, probably `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a String array:

```
String[] stringArr = new String[3]
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

stringArr[0] = "abc";
stringArr[1] = "bca";
stringArr[2] = "cba";

for(int i = 0; i<String.length; i++)
{
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(stringArr[i]));
}
```